# Uncertainty propagation through a twice-weighted average

Tags: thermal-radiation, spectroscopy, error-analysis

I am collecting the intensity of radiation as a function of wavelength. I want to take this data and average it so that I can have an average intensity for a spectral band. In my average, I want to weight by two factors – the uncertainty and another factor dictated by Planck's curve, as I care more about values that correspond to high intensity.

I also want to estimate the uncertainty associated with this twice-weighted average, but I'm unsure how to do this.

I have seen some posts here, for example [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/15197/how-do-you-find-the-uncertainty-of-a-weighted-average). However, I don't know if the error for this average will propagate as described there or if the second weighting complicates matters.

Comment: Hey, can you clarify what you mean by: What is the uncertainty? And what is the factor decided by Planck curve?

Comment: **What is the uncertainty:** Each spectral data point has an uncertainty/error associated with it, based on the equipment we are using. I know this uncertainty but I want to know how that uncertainty propagates through the weighted average. i.e. I will have a value for the weighted average, but what is its error? **Planck curve factor:** This is likely to be an integrated area associated with each spectral data point (potentially aggregated into bands), divided by the total integrated area I am measuring over. i.e. I will integrate the Planck curve to get these factors.
Does that clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a smooth function, the data points are not (!) statistically independent. Instead, neighbouring data points are similar and therefore correlated. This complicates things, mathematically. Thus, one way to tackle this problem could be as follows:

1. First calculate the correlation length of the dataset. Suppose you find that the correlation length is $r$.
2. Now, only consider every $r^{th}$ datapoint. Thus use the simple formula
   \begin{align}
   y &= \frac{\sum_{i=1}^N w_i x_{i}}{\sum_{i=1}^N w_i}
   =  \frac{1}{N \bar{w}}\sum_{i=1}^N w_i x_{i}
   ~~~\textrm{where $w_i$ are the weights} \\
   \Rightarrow \sigma_y^2 &\approx 
   \sum_{i=1}^N
   \left(
   \frac{\partial y}{\partial x_{i}}
   \right)^2 \sigma_{x_{i}}^2
   =
   \frac{1}{(N \bar{w})^2}
   \sum_{i=1}^N
   w_i^2 \sigma_{x_{i}}^2
   \end{align}
   *Mathematical details*: I implicitly replaced the dataset $\{x_i\}$ by $x_{1+i\cdot r}$. Thus, I took only every $r^{th}$ data point.

The described reduction of the dataset is unsatisfactory, because we do not use the full information contained in the dataset. Therefore, you might be interested in using the mathematically more proper formula
$$
\sigma_y^2 \approx \sum_{i=1}^N
\left(
\frac{\partial y}{\partial x_{i}}
\right)^2 \sigma_{x_{i}}^2
+
2 \sum_{i = 1}^{N-1} 
\sum_{j = i+1}^{N} 
\frac{\partial y}{\partial x_{i}}
\frac{\partial y}{\partial x_{j}}
Cov[x_i, x_j]
$$
Here we included the second term of the Taylor expansion, where $Cov[x_i, x_j]$ denotes the covariance between $x_i$ and $x_j$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm surprised not to see the weights appear in either equation for uncertainty. I would have expected, for example, that if you wighted one point in a dataset more, then its error would contribute more to the uncertainty of the average.

Comment: Maybe you missed my formula. I wrote it more explicit.

Comment: Thank you, that's very useful!